# Gravitron Physics vs Spinning a ball in a glass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, friction, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

I have experimented with trying to "lift" up a ball inside a glass by spinning it.  It works with a wine glass in which the top is narrower than the bottom but not with a vertical glass (I've used marbles and a small rubber bouncy ball).

If I'm not mistaken, the Gravitron amusement park ride is able to keep people "stuck" to a vertical wall due to the force of friction counteracting the force of gravity when the ride spins fast enough.

So why is it that a glass with vertical sides cannot lift up a ball since there should be a force of friction upward counteracting the force of gravity just like a gravitron?

Comment: Not clear. You seem to be claiming that a ball can rotate on the sides of a wine glass which are narrower at the top than the bottom. This does not seem possible because then there is no vertical component of force to oppose gravity.

Comment: @sammygerbil The wine glass is inverted, so the opening (top) is down.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in that there is a force of friction upward that can counteract the force of gravity. However, because of the spherical shape of the marble, this exerts a torque on the marble which causes it to roll out of the glass. On the other hand, a vertical glass would be able to lift a cylinder (parallel to the glass) because, that way, the centripetal force applied by the glass would be able to counteract the torque mentioned above, and the cylinder would stick to the glass, assuming that there is sufficient friction.

Regarding the gravitron, while it could work with vertical sides and relying on friction, it is actually sloped like the wine glass.

Comment: SO how exactly does the centripetal force applied by the glass counteract the torque exerted on the cylinder?